# use regex Matcher.group to copy words

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm interested in putting the numbers into a an array of `String`'s but can't get the usage of regex and groups quite worked out.

code:

```
package regex;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "A: 123/456  BC: 78/90  NEw: 105 E: 0  BK: 10 None: 0%";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+): (\\d+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        String[] as = new String[7];
        as[2] = m.group();  //array list??
        for (int i = 2; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println(as[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+): (\\d+)");`

into

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+): (\\d+/{0,1}\\d*%{0,1})");`

Comment: `/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/regex/src/regex/Regex.java:37: error: illegal escape character
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+): (\\d+\/{0,1}\\d*\%{0,1})"); `

Answer (score 1):

`Matcher` does not work the way you try to use it. The `group()` method returns last matched group. To actually tell the matcher to match something, you need to call `find()` first. `find()` returns a boolean that tells whether or not the matcher managed to find the next match, so that you can loop through all the matches like this:

```
while (m.find()) {
    String text = m.group();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: ok, I saw that, I just can't see why it has to loop, but I'll look into that more.  thanks :)

Comment: Looping allows lazy matching - instead of searching for all the matches, we can stop at arbitrary moment. I guess it could have been done with `getMatch(int num)`-type interface as well, but it has been designed in this way instead. Maybe for explicitness?

Comment: also, your usage of "lazy" helps me better understand its meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the regular expression:

```
(\w+): +(\S+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

e.g.:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("(\\w+): +(\\S+)");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "A: 123/456  BC: 78/90  NEw: 105 E: 0  BK: 10 None: 0%";
    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A: 123/456
BC: 78/90
NEw: 105
E: 0
BK: 10
None: 0%
```

If you want to get the *name*, `matcher.group(1)`, or the *number*, with `matcher.group(2)`.

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("(\\w+): +(\\S+)");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "A: 123/456  BC: 78/90  NEw: 105 E: 0  BK: 10 None: 0%";
    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("Number: " + matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Name: A
Number: 123/456
Name: BC
Number: 78/90
Name: NEw
Number: 105
Name: E
Number: 0
Name: BK
Number: 10
Name: None
Number: 0%
```

Comment: ohhh, thanks, I was using `matcher.group(int)` incorrectly.  thanks for showing usage.

Answer (score 0):

just thought I'd throw this out there for a reaction:

```
package regex;

import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Map.Entry> l = new ArrayList<>();
        String monitor = "A: 123/456  BC: 78/90  NEw: 105 E: 0  BK: 10 None: 0%";
        Pattern outerPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+): (\\d+)");
        Matcher outerMatcher = outerPattern.matcher(monitor);
        String outerGroup = null;
        int i = 0;
        Pattern innerPattern;
        Matcher innerMatcher;
        String innerGroup = null;
        while (outerMatcher.find()) {
            outerGroup = outerMatcher.group();
            System.out.println(outerGroup);
            innerPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+): (\\d+)");
            innerMatcher = innerPattern.matcher(outerGroup);
            while (innerMatcher.find()) {
                innerGroup = innerMatcher.group();
                System.out.println(innerGroup);
                Map.Entry<String, Integer> entr = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("exmpleString", 42);
                l.add(entr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```